# Infinite Scroll - To identify the pagination url pattern

Tags: jquery, scroll, pagination, infinite

I am trying to find the pagination url pattern for this site: http://www.thetradefinder.co.uk/searchresult.aspx?loc=london&name=plumbers
, which has infinite scrolling. I looked in chrome/firebug developer tools > network, under TYPE: XHR, for the response code and header...but no luck.

I see is google map stuff when you load the page via Get  and the BindSearchresult . I think the answer lies somewhere in the POST Bindsearchresult.

Answer (score 0):

Request Payload as "{'counter':'x'}" it's send to http://www.thetradefinder.co.uk/searchresult.aspx/BindSearchResult where x goes from 10 plus 10.

Comment: Thanks JC. So how would I modify the thetradefinder.co,uk url, so that it has pagination, for scraping.  For example http://www.pinko.com/en-gb/catalog/index/springsummer type site has infinite scrolling, so it has pagination url pattern as 
http://www.pinko.com/en-gb/catalog/index/springsummer?pg=4.  Trying to do same for http://www.thetradefinder.co.uk/searchresult.aspx?loc=london&name=plumbers to scrape.